# range doesn't work second time in an if statement

Tags: python

Trying to solve a hackerrank problem. Why range doesn't work the second time in this if statement (it works the first range code).

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

if n % 2 == 1:
    print("Weird")
elif n % 2 == 0 and list(range(2, 6)): #This works
    print("Not Weird")
elif n % 2 == 0 and list(range(6, 21)): #This doesn't work
    print("Weird")
elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Any way to make it work somehow? Or any suggestion to use another built-in function for the same purpose?

Comment: Did you mean to do `elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 6)`?

Comment: Using `list(range(2, 6))` as a condition is equivalent to just using `True`.

Comment: @not_speshal. That actually worked. Thanks a lot! I guess I need to understand the documentation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and range(2,6)` always evaluates as `True` and
because you're using `elif`, if it matches the first condition it doesn't continue. You probably meant to use `n in list(range())` but if you want to check if a number is between to others use `<` or `>`:

```py
elif n % 2 == 0 and 1 < n < 6
```